# I get "Attempting to JIT compile method 'Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory:Create"

Tags: xamarin.forms, ninject

I am using portable.ninject 3.3.1 and want to access a ninject object the following way:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

    public App (params INinjectModule[] platformModules)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

        // Register core services
        Kernel = new StandardKernel(new FeruiCoreModule(), new FeruiNavModule(mainPage.Navigation));

        // Register platform specific services
        Kernel.Load(platformModules);


        // Get the MainViewModel from the IoC
        mainPage.BindingContext = Kernel.Get<MainViewModel>();

        MainPage = mainPage;
    }
```

At "mainPage.BindingContext = Kernel.Get();"
I get: Attempting to JIT compile method 'Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory:Create (System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo)' while running in aot-only mode.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you read this blog about using ninject?https://medium.com/@chrisverwijs/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-ninject-for-dependency-injection-in-c-68a125bd7fa4

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. Make sure you are actually using Portable.Ninject. Using the not-portable version of Ninject causes this problem, but once I switched to Portable.Ninject and REBUILT the entire solution the problem went away.